# Why is mysqldump not saving newly added databases?

Tags: mysqldump

I am using the following command to backup all mysql databases in script that is run as cronjob.

```
mysqldump -u root -p'***' --all-databases > backupdb.sql
```

I have added new databases recently and I noticed that the new databases are not saved in the `backupdb.sql`.  What am I missing?

Comment: I created these new databases using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Unagaswamy, before mysqldump did you checked mysql >show databases ; what it show.

Comment: `mysql>show databases` does show all the new databases.

Comment: have you checked in root user privilege of your new created database or not

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question! Are you asking if the root has privileges on the new databases? If so, yes, the root does!

Answer (score 0):

1) check your last 10 lines of dump file

```
 tail dump.sql
```

it should show your dump file properly completed or not.

2) grep the database name in dump file

```
 cat dump.sql | grep newdb
```

with the above 2 steps you can find is your backup is completed propery or not and the new database exists or not.